# Dock - Remove spacer?

Tags: macos, dock

Is there a way to remove the spacer between the downloads stack and apps?

[image: Dock]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible through normal means. And by that I mean I doubt you could change this without hacking the OS.

I know you can add spaces:

[Adjust width of spacer between Mac OS dock icons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250723/adjust-width-of-spacer-between-mac-os-dock-icons)

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="small-spacer-tile";}' && killall Dock
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'
```

Those are the only space customizations I am aware of.

I know this is not the answer you were hoping for but I believe it to be the correct answer.

Comment: and as an addendum (forgive me for being pedantic...) that is the separator between documents/folders and applications

Comment: Yup, that is a good clarification! It just turns out that you can in fact add that vertical spacer or a blank spacer to the dock at will. I just don't know of any way to remove that spacer. Far as I can tell its just designed into the dock.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Concerning pedantism: The attached screenshot I was referring to shows only the downloads folder.

Answer (score -2):

"long click" on space in the dock .  a little window appears to delete the space

Comment: Tested this on macOS10.15, does not work.